# How to access a CSS class that is loaded via a iframe on a page

Tags: css, facebook, iframe, html, facebook-iframe

I have just added a 'Like' button from Facebook. The site is in Arabic, and I have added the necessary Arabic language locals to the FB code. Now the problem is the Icons are displaying slightly different, and I can see that can be controlled by CSS. The FB Code loads an iframe and within that there is a SPAN that has a class that controls the position of the Facebook (blue 'f' icon) which is overlapping over the text. When I try using FireBug and re-position it it words fine. My question is how can I write a CSS code that I can change the value on that iframe loaded CSS  from my local CSS file ? The code is as follows:

=== Code on the iFrame that is loading ===

```
<div class="connect_button_slider">
<div class="connect_button_container">
<a class="connect_widget_like_button clearfix like_button_no_like">
<div class="tombstone_cross"></div>
<span class="liketext">أعجبني</span>
</a>
</div>
```

===

## The CSS that is loaded by FireBug

```
.button_count .like_button_dark .like_button_no_like .liketext, .button_count .connect_widget_like_button .liketext {
    background-position: -1px -47px;
}
```

====

I need to change the "class"="liketext".
I want to change the value of "background-position: -1px -47px;" from that to the following:

```
background-position: 38px -47px;
```

====

Now I have my local CSS file, how will I be able to access that element "liketext" and change the value from "-1" to "38" ...

The page, if you want to check, is on the following link ...

URL: http://www.majalla.com/arb/2011/09/article55227042

On top of the article you will find the facebook icon/like overlapping just next to the print icon.

Comment: can't be done with CSS, but possible with javascript.

Comment: Absolutely riddled with typos. Please take more care. Have submitted an edit to fix them.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for fixing my Spelling error's. It was my mistake, as I was actually in a hurry and just typed the whole thing on my laptop, which I'm still getting used to ... rest assured, I hope this will not be repealedted  ... Oh Sorry *repeated .... just kidding :). Thanks again, and best of regards. Fawaz

Comment: @usoban maybe you could be a bit more detailed ?! Would be interested too how you would solve this with javascript!

Comment: I've had similar problem myself, so I went to look at the old code and it turns out I didn't actually manipuate objects inside iframe, but rather outside. And crossframe scripting is not possible due to sandbox, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like telling you that your work here was pretty much wasted. You can't influence an external iframe with css - that's why Facebook does it that way, to have full control over their icons. Anyway it's a shame that the like button doesn't get displayed properly, but all you can (and should) do is submitting a bug report to facebook!

By the way, try taking care of your spelling: It's that, not tath and THAT spelling makes it really hard to read your question ;)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the feedback. I guess you are right on the point. Although I did find the following link trying to explain out the whole thing, I believe this might be even referencing to the Old Facebook Like-box & API's. But give it a look and advise me do u think it is worth to try it out ?

http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/

And the final option is to report a bug as u advised. I already saw 2 more users complaining about the same issue.

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91225

Best of regards,

Fawaz

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that only refers to the old like box where you were allowed to add a custom css file, but it only worked for the like BOX, not for the like button, so it wouldn't be of any use for you anyway. Bug report is the last resort :/ Although I'd be interested how usoban would solve it with javascript, I never heard of any way doing that.